# How to embed zone data from www.educationcounts.govt.nz into my own Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

On this website https://www.educationcounts.govt.nz/find-school/school/profile?school=780&district=16&region=3, a schools location is shown on the map, and certain schools have enrollment zones, so only certain areas of the school allow students to enroll. Is there a way to add the option of embedding the zoned map into another website? For example, if the school wanted to embed the map on their website? [Its an OpenStreetMap using Leaflet]

Comment: Welcome to SO! What feature are you trying to provide exactly? For the mentioned site to enable a school site embedding a similar map? For the school site to build its own map, duplicating the enrolment area data?

Comment: We've been asked by some schools, if there is a way of using the zoned map of their school into their website, so I was wondering if OSM or Leaflet have an option once a map has been rendered with enrolment area etc, for a user to embed the result on their website, I'm not sure if the option is viable but needed to ask on behalf

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be referring to the highlighted area in the maps in the [educationcounts.govt.nz](https://www.educationcounts.govt.nz/find-school/school/profile?school=780&district=16&region=3) website:

[image: enrollment zone]

A bit of fiddling with my [web browser's network monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) reveals that the data for that enrollment area is transferred via GeoJSON (wrapped inside  a trivial JSON data structure) through an endpoint at `https://www.educationcounts.govt.nz/js-content/school-enrolment-zone-geo-data?school=780`, where `780` is a numeric school ID. That's good news: the endpoint is not obfuscated, there's no API sign-up process, no weird stuff.

Now, there are several ways to add data to your own Leaflet map. One would be to have some javascript request data from that endpoint from your webpage, then let Leaflet parse and display that GeoJSON data, i.e.:

```
fetch('https://www.educationcounts.govt.nz/js-content/school-enrolment-zone-geo-data?school=780')
.then(function(response){return response.json()})
.then(function(json){
    var zone = L.geoJson(json.schoolZones[0]).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(zone.getBounds());
});
```

However, if you [try to run that](https://plnkr.co/edit/2sE0BapKkw6MUBIW), you'll be hit with a [CORS error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors). This means that a webpage hosted at the `educationcounts.govt.nz` domain name can request data from an endpoint hosted at the `educationcounts.govt.nz`, but if the webpage and the data endpoint are at different domains, stuff won't work.

A second approach is to set up a proxy webserver. A browser visiting your webpage would request data from an endpoint in your proxy server, and then your proxy server would request data from the `educationcounts.govt.nz` endpoint. I feel that how to set such a proxy webserver is out of the scope of this answer.

Another approach then would be a good ol' copy-paste. Note that we can do that since the [NZ Ministry of Education allows anyone to do that](https://www.educationcounts.govt.nz/site-info/privacy):

> "[...] Unless indicated otherwise for specific items [...] this copyright material is licensed for re-use under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International licence. In essence, you are free to copy, distribute and adapt the material, as long as you attribute it to [name of agency/licensor] and abide by the other licence terms.[...]

So you can just download `https://www.educationcounts.govt.nz/js-content/school-enrolment-zone-geo-data?school=780`, copy-paste the GeoJSON data into your JS code, add an attribution text, and you would be done, i.e.:

```
var geojson_for_school_780 = {
    "type": "Feature", 
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[175.228088376393515, -37.72252796906151], [175.226034730098121, -37.720644653205419], [175.22766664238091, -37.719790045099124], [175.226669852036935, -37.719494534245776], [175.226063764869849, -37.719139298407981], [175.225684377028415, -37.718639517004007], [175.229416445471969, -37.718249363032648], [175.229085250983672, -37.71615637690455], [175.232916799597604, -37.715781597614502], [175.232994305233518, -37.716138715739554], [175.233444251633273, -37.716777017700473], [175.234158364268694, -37.71640115383375], [175.236281071637421, -37.716492901297777], [175.236778969848842, -37.714982027731864], [175.23678197389944, -37.714972736633278], [175.237007068442892, -37.714289969996393], [175.237241870249363, -37.713577440478581], [175.237270572373717, -37.713490244242642], [175.240150572754345, -37.714065821500597], [175.240643435719903, -37.712513828060004], [175.243666181667777, -37.712865753620441], [175.250868816480903, -37.716764632124416], [175.251583336046906, -37.717696153282141], [175.254009088257504, -37.723034477939613], [175.253880254830392, -37.723454795140654], [175.25349101820072, -37.723784706999517], [175.253036672946649, -37.724303029748867], [175.252594231767404, -37.72400311293994], [175.251708805537902, -37.724234350926004], [175.250761189334611, -37.724405921967168], [175.248617924442527, -37.724701883851303], [175.248670831855691, -37.724983622610388], [175.248108644705894, -37.725216958649114], [175.248650574856413, -37.725715016374757], [175.249211188456741, -37.72611261827015], [175.249655009537463, -37.726795407802669], [175.249611471330013, -37.727653444472836], [175.249251932365951, -37.728735469804036], [175.24882851502224, -37.729535978099591], [175.248699477963925, -37.729951947833527], [175.248679639737873, -37.730696376073432], [175.247396212196207, -37.730617917521215], [175.246153794004499, -37.730656875737637], [175.241864451038253, -37.727794371200304], [175.241180169528519, -37.728000311784783], [175.240588231182812, -37.727848333950995], [175.240153830359304, -37.727715480402672], [175.239851710703874, -37.727454948983301], [175.239875963992915, -37.727229477760901], [175.240149140367777, -37.726915638650944], [175.240215554761789, -37.726697642096219], [175.239903506117116, -37.726453987907334], [175.239653784325327, -37.726127205552878], [175.239401725478814, -37.725855878978372], [175.23926283076392, -37.725450394672841], [175.238884215081299, -37.725544253360944], [175.238640207482177, -37.725662986352773], [175.238359547776611, -37.725743664646863], [175.237811460334513, -37.725663095694664], [175.237255020354979, -37.725649360565903], [175.236522478420255, -37.725705843488996], [175.235863906512094, -37.725769794857271], [175.235254998449847, -37.725764800151751], [175.234768745586678, -37.725649642237613], [175.23447386768197, -37.725613939759789], [175.234072007153287, -37.725513740156622], [175.233809457524046, -37.725177407031069], [175.233740971157573, -37.725003820731189], [175.233592583214886, -37.724956818310353], [175.23343240605891, -37.724868400347226], [175.233446176252102, -37.724643142640126], [175.232926621407813, -37.724158104107403], [175.232567102025371, -37.72386686778475], [175.232324859841981, -37.723743049267213], [175.231984024121715, -37.723568840798833], [175.23168917633987, -37.723418148852147], [175.230339273580199, -37.721887519404923], [175.230117128172367, -37.720706116231113], [175.229491841292969, -37.720595274641148], [175.229321718089551, -37.720651789039294], [175.229205499717182, -37.720954090252832], [175.228911973926813, -37.72096000947694], [175.22877250197385, -37.720862830025283], [175.228781549692457, -37.721145956121312], [175.228565121524923, -37.721266978437441], [175.228351630524628, -37.72147959497768], [175.228462480264795, -37.721993967796962], [175.228088376393515, -37.72252796906151]]]}, "properties": {"Office": "HM", "PolyID": 780, "INSTTYPE": "Contributing", "PolyName": "Te Ao Marama School", "SchoolID": 780, "ApprovalDate": "2017/03/16", "EffectiveDate": "2019/01/01"
    }
}

var zone_780 = L.geoJson(geojson_for_school_780,{
    attribution: "<a href='https://www.educationcounts.govt.nz/site-info/privacy'>CC-by NZ Ministry of Education</a>"
});

zone_780.addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(zone_780.getBounds());
```

See a [working example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8LWJ6EU64Jakv24V).

This has the (obvious) disadvantage of not being easy to automate if you want to do this for a thousand schools, and any updates to the original data would not be reflected in your copy. If that's an issue, it'd be time to think about automating the process.

In any case, [contacting the website staff](https://www.educationcounts.govt.nz/site-info/contact-us) might be a good idea. They might have some other channels for distributing the schools' geographical data that are not advertised, and they might be helpful specially if the final recipients are schools.

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan for your great suggestions and working example, I'd taken leave from my role and back on board catching up with emails so am very appreciative to read your feedback. Your suggestion of the copy  and paste method would be a great option, but would this cause any charges on the educationcounts.govt.nz domain with regards to the OSM and leaflet?